# setsockopt fails while kernel TLS option enabling

Tags: c, linux, ssl, kernel

I am learning about [kernel TLS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/tls.html#kernel-tls) on kernel 5.3 version (Fedora 30 and 31) but stuck even on enabling ULP:

```c
//  tls.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>     
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/tls.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h> 
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

int main() {
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1) {
        perror("socket creation");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_TCP, TCP_ULP, "tls", sizeof("tls")) == -1 )   {
        perror("tls init");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close (sock);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then:

```sh
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_available_ulp
tls
$ gcc tls.c -O0 -g
$ lsmod | grep tls
$ ./a.out 
tls init: No such file or directory

$ lsmod | grep tls
$ sudo ./a.out 
tls init: Unknown error 524

$ lsmod | grep tls
tls                    57344  0
$ ./a.out 
tls init: Unknown error 524
$
```

I don't know where I am wrong. It looks so simple in [Kernel TLS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/tls.html#kernel-tls) docs:

> **Creating a TLS connection**
>
> First create a new TCP socket and set the TLS ULP.
>
> ```
> sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
>
> setsockopt(sock, SOL_TCP, TCP_ULP, "tls", sizeof("tls"));
> ```
>
> Setting the TLS ULP allows us to set/get TLS socket options. Currently
>   only the symmetric encryption is handled in the kernel. After the TLS
>   handshake is complete, we have all the parameters required to move the
>   data-path to the kernel. There is a separate socket option for moving
>   the transmit and the receive into the kernel.

I don't understand how I can enable in kernel TLS and what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Was your kernel compiled with kernel TLS support? Apparently 524 is EOPNOTSUPP.

Comment: Thanks !
@user253751
[user@localhost ~]$ cat /boot/config-5.3.13-300.fc31.x86_64 | grep -i CONFIG_TLS
CONFIG_TLS=m

Comment: Thanks!
@jww
I just took it from the documentation: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/tls.html#kernel-tls

Comment: I think this is an issue with the tls module. Also see [Issue 1778348](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1778348) in the Red Hat bugzilla. Sorry I did not cite this SO question. I thought I was doing something wrong. In hindsight I think you uncovered an issue.

Comment: @jww Thanks! Your comment prompted me to check this code on another distribution. Oracle 8 with 4.18 was available but with same behavior :(

Answer (score 0):

### Solving your issue

First thing to do is

```
sudo modprobe tls
```

Also try `sudo rmmod tls && sudo modprobe tls`.

It resolved the "**No such file or directory**" issue for me.

### Transport endpoint is not connected

Then another error appeared in `setsockopt`: "**Transport endpoint is not connected**" when doing by [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/tls.html#kernel-tls)

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
setsockopt(sock, SOL_TCP, TCP_ULP, "tls", sizeof("tls"));
```

I don't know why code from documentation *does not work* (at least on my debian 12). But ok, if the error says "not connected" let's connect it then.

All you need to do is to create a server and client sockets and make `connect()`. You can easily find them with google. **Then** you do `setsockopt TCP_ULP` on client/server and it works. Tested myself